# reasons for and against meta-refresh in the context of a login page

Tags: php

within my login code (index.php) there is a section for facebook login. it checks whether or not the user has been logged in. now i can't use headers to redirect the user to a different page because it produces the error

> ```
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> ```
>
> (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kite\index.php:81) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kite\index.php on line
>   196

so as a result i've resorted to using to meta-refresh

```
    <?php 
                //if user is logged in already
                if ($user): ?>
                <?php 
                //redirect them to the user sonline page
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="1; URL=main.php">'; 
                //if user is not logged in
                else: ?>
                <input name="fblogin" type="button" value="Login with Facebook" class="fblogin" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>'"/>
                <?php endif ?>
```

what are the advantages and disadvantages of this method?

thanking you in advance

---

all i have on line 81 is

```
<?php // include the hashing class  
require ("resources/phpass/PasswordHash.php");
```

Comment: can you post the original code that produces that error?

Comment: Seriously? It's one of [the most popular errors](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in history.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that we have a very nice [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); to quote an example: "What kind of questions should I not ask here?
[...] your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"

Comment: i haven't asked about the error - i have asked about the advantages and disadvantages of using meta refresh as a replacement

Comment: the point is `there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In login and logout context, header() will stop the browser from caching the page, which stores some sensitive information of the user.

You need to send header **BEFORE** any of your HTML will be displayed.

There are some more reasons behind header(), to make it preferable to the developers. But in login context, I think that's enough.

Answer (score 3):

I know this problem. It's about unnecessary spaces in your code-you have **a space** or **character** before sending header. So check your code and **remove all spaces** before `<?php` tag and after `?>` tag.

Hope this helps!